# GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR parameter on /etc/default/grub

Tags: boot, grub2, customization

I'm curious about this parameter, all I know you can set any name with echo

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='echo some_random_name'
```

and it's displays the name that I set there in the grub2 menu.
But I'm curious why does it change back to purple background when I restore the previous value

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
```

where is that setting defined? is it in grub.cfg? or is in some of the files in grub.d folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant lines are in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` between

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
```

and

```
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
```

Since `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is generated by using the files in `/etc/grub.d/` you should take a look at `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`. The variable `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` is used in this file several times to determine Grub's appearance. It also depends on the existence of several files in your system (background images, themes).